# Calculate distance from all points to all lines within 10km using FME?

Tags: point, geometry, fme-form, line, perpendicular

I have a polyline shapefile and a point shapefile.  The points are along the polylines.  There are over 100 lines and over 10,000 points.  I want to calculate the perpendicular distance from every point to every line within 10km *except* for the line that the point is on.

I'm happy to calculate lines representing these distances.  My first thought was to use the **[NeighborFinder](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/FME_Transformers.htm#Transformers/neighborfinder.htm)** transformer.  However, this only seems to calculate the nearest line which is the line that the point is on (zero distance).

**Sample image of data:**
[image]

Is there a way to have the NeighborFinder find *all* of the closest lines within 10km?  How else can I accomplish this?  Perhaps a looper?

Comment: PolylineAnalyzer creates vertex numbers, angle, distance can be done with a nearset neighbour (use a tester to remove the first point) https://store.safe.com/transformers/PolylineAnalyzer.htm

Comment: @Mapperz, I don't see how the PolylineAnalyzer will help me here.  I want to calculate distance from the points to all lines.  I don't need to analyse vertices or angles of the polylines.

Comment: there is more to the custom transformer use can use tester for the angle to be perpendicular distance with the nearest neighbour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have figured this one out.

I ended up using the NeighborFinder as I initially suspected.  The trick is to store all candidate details in a list (I called it NeighbourList).

[image]

I then connected that to a ListExploder to create features from all elements in the list.  Then I used a tester to filter out the features with a distance of zero.  Finally, I used a VertexCreator to add a vertex at the candidate location to make a line.

The results are:

[image]

There is still some work needed to get rid of non-perpendicular lines at the bends of the black lines.  But generally, the results are good.

[image]

Note the gap is where the lines are greater than 10km apart.